# Best budget microphone to record foley

Tags: recording, foley, microphone, budget

Hi,

As a starting sound designer I want to record my own foley. But for that I need a good microphoone to record foley. I don't have a big budget for expensive microphone, so I am looking for a microhone for foley for a nice price.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

+1 on the NT1a. It's my go-to for delicate, quiet sounds unless the character better fits my MKH-50; comparing those price points between the two mics, I'd say the Røde represents a rather screaming value. Heck, some take a pair out into the field for ultra-low-noise stereo ambiences!

Answer (score 2):

Røde NT1-A?

(5dBA self noise so it will challenge your room and preamps.)

Answer (score 1):

For really low budget, I have been happy with the MXL microphones like the 770 (around $100) or the v87 (around $200). Both will stand you in good stead as long as you are not planning on doing any super quiet recording.  I strongly recommend that you invest in a shockmount whichever microphone you buy, and windscreens if you intend on doing any field recording.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest the Rode NT1A, I believe that it still comes with a shock mount.  It has a low noise floor and a fairly flat frequency response.

Answer (score 0):

What's a nice price for you?

I've compared a rode ntg3 to my neumann kmr81 and didn't feel the neumann was much better, if at all, which is awesome for a 700us$/475€
It's good for field recording as well.